# Javascript functions not running

Tags: javascript

I'm working on a project for school and am having trouble getting everything to run. Currently the prompts, "Enter your year-end income" and "Enter your taxable deductions for the year" will run and the output is:

```
Welcome to COP 2500 Tax Service!

Your taxable income is $5300
```

I'm looking to get:

```
Welcome to COP 2500 Tax Service!

Your taxable income is $5300

Based on a taxable income of $5300 your tax rate is 10 percent

Your calculated taxes owed are $530

You overpaid your taxes, you will receive a refund of $120

Thank you for using COP 2500 Tax Service!
```

Any Help would be great. Thanks

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
   <script type="text/javascript">
   const TEN = 0.10;
   const FIFTEEN = 0.15;
   const TWENTYFIVE = 0.25;
   const TWENTYEIGHT = 0.28;
   const THRITYTHREE = 0.33;
   const THIRTYFIVE = 0.35;
   const THREENINETYSIX = 0.396;


function getTaxRate(inIncome); {
   var income = parseInt(inIncome);
   var taxRate;

   if (income <= 8925 && income >= 0) {
    taxRate = TEN;
   }
   else if (income >= 8926 && income <= 36250) {
    taxRate = FIFTEEN;
   }
   else if (income >= 36251 && income <= 87850) {
    taxRate = TWENTYFIVE;
   }
   else if (income >= 87851 && income <= 183250) {
    taxRate = TWENTYEIGHT;
   }
   else if (income >= 183251 && income <= 398350) {
    taxRate = THRITYTHREE;
   }
   else if (income >= 398351 && income <= 400000) {
    taxRate = THIRTYFIVE;
   }
   else if {
    taxRate = THREENINETYSIX;
   }
   return taxRate;
   }   



   function calculateTaxes(inTaxableIncome, inTaxRate) {
  var income = parseInt(inTaxableIncome);
  var rate = parseFloat(inTaxRate);
  var taxesOwed = income * rate;
  return taxesOwed;
  }

function refundOrPay(inTaxesOwed, inTaxesPaid) {
  var taxesOwed = parseInt(inTaxesOwed);
  var taxesPaid = parseInt(inTaxesPaid);
  var taxDifference = taxesOwed - taxesPaid;
  return taxDifference;
}

  </script>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        document.writeln("Welcome to COP 2500 Tax Service!<br>");

        //Determine the tax rate
        var income = prompt("Enter your year-end income");
        var deductions = prompt("Enter your taxable deductions for the year", "");

        var taxableIncome = (parseInt(income) - parseInt(deductions));

        document.writeln("Your taxable income is $" + taxableIncome + "<br>");
        var rate = getTaxRate(taxableIncome);

        document.writeln("Based on a taxable income of $" + taxableIncome + " your tax rate is " + rate * 100 + " percent<br>")

         var taxesOwed = calculateTaxes(taxableIncome, rate);

        document.writeln("Your calculated taxes owed are $" + taxesOwed + "<br>");

        var taxesPaid = prompt("Enter the taxes you paid for the year", "");
        var taxResult = refundOrPay(taxesOwed, taxesPaid);

        if (taxResult == 0) {
          document.writeln("Congratulations you broke even!<br>");
        } else if (taxResult > 0) {
          document.writeln("Unfortunately you still owe more, please pay an additional $" + taxResult + " by April 15, 2014<br>");
        } else {
          document.writeln("You overpaid your taxes, you will recieve a refund of $" + (-1 * taxResult) + "<br>");
}

        document.writeln("Thank you for using COP 2500 Tax Service!");
    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: @charlietfl Yes there is. Please at least research before claiming false information.

Comment: @charlietfl https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const

Comment: The problem it stops there is here: `function getTaxRate(inIncome); {` notice the semicolon? Please check the console to spot more errors like this, if you don't know how to do that just tell us what browser you are using and we will help you.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek Thanks, I took that out and am getting the same results. I don't know what that is but would like to figure that out. I'm just using safari. Thanks for the response

Comment: Think of the `console` as a place that detects errors and shows them to you. You can also write JavaScript directly on it. See if this http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8525/how-to-open-the-javascript-console-in-different-browsers helps you on reaching it. From there when the scripts runs it will tell you on what line things went run, and you can debug from there.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek hell yeah man, I just figured it out with that. Thanks a lot